# How to use leaflet.js heat with pane?

Tags: leaflet

I want to show/hide Leaflet.heat(https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) layer, and new pane should somehow do this.
But is there any support for panes on Leaflet.heat?
This code does not work.

```
var heatPane = map.createPane("heat");
var heat = L.heatLayer([], {
  radius: 10,
  maxZoom: 6,
  pane: "heat"
}).addTo(map);
heat.addLatLng([44,7])
heat.addLatLng([44,7])
```

UPD: I can use heat._heat._canvas.style.display = "none" to hide heat layer, but I don't think it is a good practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is seems current **release** version of leaflet-heat.js does not support using `pane` option. You can use **beta/development** version if you want and you can achieve your requirements by just setting style on the pane.

Check out the code below:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function(e){
  if(document.readyState != 'complete') return;

  var map = L.map('map').setView([44, 7], 12);
  var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {}).addTo(map);
  var heatPane = map.createPane("heat");
  var heat = L.heatLayer([[44, 7], [44, 7], [44, 7], [44, 7]], {
    radius: 10,
    maxZoom: 6,
    pane: "heat"
  }).addTo(map);

  document.getElementById("btnShow").onclick = function(){
    heatPane.style.display = 'block';
  };

  document.getElementById("btnHide").onclick = function(){
    heatPane.style.display = 'none';
  };
};
```

```css
#map {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.3.4/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.3.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/src/HeatLayer.js"></script>
<script src="http://mourner.github.io/simpleheat/simpleheat.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="btnHide">Hide</button>
  <button id="btnShow">Show</button>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

**P.S**: You can uncomment the code and use release version of the script but it will not work because current release version of leaflet-heat draws canvas on default map layer.